# Run Minecraft Command from bbPress

Tags: php, wordpress, minecraft, bukkit, bbpress

Ok, hi guys. This may be really weird question to ask of you, but is there a way that when someone on my Minecraft Server forums creates a topic in the forum: "Introduce Yourself" it gives them money. I already have the command to do that, and hope this can be done.

Also is it possible they can only do it once under their forums account.

Thank You so much in advance.

Comment: it is probably possible if your MC server has some sort of plugin to interface with your bbPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try doing it over [rcon](http://www.wiki.vg/Rcon). rcon is a very simple protocol for server administration that basically gives you remote access to the server admin console. Writing a PHP script that connects to rcon and runs a command to give a specific player something shouldn't be hard if there already is a command for doing it.

Comment: Any way that does not require an extra port

Comment: @user2102757: That would probably require your code to speak the minecraft protocol, which is a big bunch of ugliness. Alternatively, you could probably create a server mod for speaking two protocols on one port... but really, what's the big issue with opening another port?